# Max and Min not giving true Max and Min

Tags: max, min

I am struggling greatly with creating a query.

[actual query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQP2J.png)

I have been trying to write a query that will give me the old_value for the minimum id and the new_value for the maximum id.  [expected query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxxlR.png) .  In my example I have taken 2 units and reclassed them twice.  I'm concerned about what the unit originally was (min of old value) and what it finally was (max of new value) regardless of how many times it was reclassed (the 2nd image is what I would expect).  Every query I've written either gives me all the records (even when I enter a max or min) or only gives me the min/max of a single record for a day even though their may be multiple records for that.  Also, if a unit is only reclassed once I would want to make sure that is captured as well (the min/min for that unit would be the same, of course).

I would appreciate some assistance as I'm not a DBA and I struggle with SQL and I don't have anyone in my company that can assist.  Would it also be possible to provide an explanation of why sometimes entering MIN or MAX does not truly give the Min or Max?  I apologize in advance if I've formatted this wrong.  This is first time I've posted code on here. Thank you!

EDIT: I've added in some more code.  This will work correctly if I run it for just one day.  When I run it for more than one day, it won't correctly. It adds in the wrong min/max combination. [Query when ran for more than one day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWL9O.jpg)

`enter select  id, unit_id, trunc (log_ts), old_value, new_value from col$unit_action_log where action_ind='RECLASS'  and trunc(log_ts)='02-JUL-20' order by 1 asc, 2 asc;`

````
``` select distinct t2.site_id as site_id, t2.month as reclass_month ,t2.count_waste as coll_num, (t2.volume/1000) as volume,
 t3.old as start_class, t2.new as end_class
from svc$sites sites
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = sites.timezone_id
join (select 
trunc(ual.log_ts) as Month,


u2.unit_num as Count_waste,u2.volume as volume, u2.unit_num as unit_num,
ual.unit_id, max(ual.id) as max_id, c.id as c_id, u2.coll_id as u2_id, ual.old_value as old, ual.new_value as new, c.site_id as site_id
from col$unit_action_log ual
join (select ual2.unit_id as unit_id, max(ual2.id) as M_id
from col$unit_action_log ual2 
 join col$units u2 on u2.id=ual2.unit_id
 join col$collections c on c.id=u2.coll_id
INNER JOIN svc$sites site ON site.code = u2.site_id
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = site.timezone_id

where  ( ual2.action_ind='RECLASS') and 

             ( trunc(CAST( (from_tz(CAST(ual2.log_ts AS TIMESTAMP),'UTC') AT TIME ZONE timezone.java_id) AS TIMESTAMP) )  BETWEEN '13-JUL-20' AND '13-JUL-20') 
--( ual2.action_ind='RECLASS' and trunc(ual2.log_ts)='13-JUL-20')
group by unit_id)  ual2 on ual.unit_id=ual2.unit_id and ual.id= ual2.m_id 
 join col$units u2 on u2.id=ual.unit_id
 join col$collections c on c.id=u2.coll_id
INNER JOIN svc$sites site ON site.code = u2.site_id
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = site.timezone_id
group by ual.unit_id,u2.unit_num,u2.volume,c.id,
trunc(ual.log_ts),

c.site_id,u2.coll_id, u2.site_id,ual.old_value, ual.new_value)t2  on t2.site_id=sites.code
 join (select   
 trunc(ual.log_ts) as Month,

 u2.unit_num as Count_waste,u2.volume as volume, u2.unit_num as unit_num,
ual.unit_id, min(ual.id) as max_id, c.id as c_id, u2.coll_id as u2_id, ual.old_value as old, ual.new_value as new, c.site_id as site_id
from col$unit_action_log ual
join (select ual2.unit_id as unit_id, min(ual2.id) as M_id
from col$unit_action_log ual2 
 join col$units u2 on u2.id=ual2.unit_id
 join col$collections c on c.id=u2.coll_id
INNER JOIN svc$sites site ON site.code = u2.site_id
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = site.timezone_id
where ( ual2.action_ind='RECLASS') and 

             ( trunc(CAST( (from_tz(CAST(ual2.log_ts AS TIMESTAMP),'UTC') AT TIME ZONE timezone.java_id) AS TIMESTAMP) )  BETWEEN '13-JUL-20' AND '13-JUL-20') 

group by unit_id)  ual2 on ual.unit_id=ual2.unit_id and ual.id= ual2.m_id 
  join col$units u2 on u2.id=ual.unit_id
 join col$collections c on c.id=u2.coll_id
INNER JOIN svc$sites site ON site.code = u2.site_id
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = site.timezone_id
group by ual.unit_id,u2.unit_num,u2.volume,c.id,
trunc(ual.log_ts),

c.site_id,u2.coll_id, u2.site_id,ual.old_value, ual.new_value) t3
 on t3.site_id=sites.code
order by 3; ```
````

Comment: It would be easier to check your code if you use the block monospace marker ``` to enclose your code. That way, you can show line formatting.

Comment: Can you please explain that in simpler terms?  I’m not sure what you are asking. Thanks.

Comment: Is this oracle?

Comment: Yes, it is Oracle.

Comment: Start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, extract a [mcve] and, if you didn't find a solution yourself doing that, [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: I've edited my question.  I hope it is better.  My background is not in programming, it's in nursing.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong  with my formatting.  I would be glad to format my code properly if someone would explain how to do that.  The tutorial didn't make much sense.                                                                          I'm in a different field now and yes, it is a production database.  People get into SQL from different backgrounds, they all don't have computer science degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I took a new approach to this query.  There is likely a better way to do it, but, this works.

````
to_char(trunc(q1.month, 'MON'), 'MON YYYY')
,  (q1.volume/1000), q1.unit_num, q1.old, q2.new,q1.site_id
from(
select   
cast(trunc((from_tz(cast(ual.log_ts as timestamp), 'UTC') at time zone timezone.java_id)) as timestamp) as Month
, u2.unit_num as Count_waste,u2.volume as volume, u2.unit_num as unit_num,
ual.unit_id, min(ual.id) as max_id, c.id as c_id, u2.coll_id as u2_id, ual.old_value as old,
c.site_id as site_id
from col$unit_action_log ual
join (select ual2.unit_id as unit_id, min(ual2.id) as M_id
from col$unit_action_log ual2 
join col$units u2 on u2.id=ual2.unit_id
join col$collections c on c.id=u2.coll_id
INNER JOIN svc$sites site ON site.code = u2.site_id
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = site.timezone_id
where ( ual2.action_ind='RECLASS') and 
---and trunc(ual2.log_ts)='13-JUL-20')
           ( trunc(CAST( (from_tz(CAST(ual2.log_ts AS TIMESTAMP),'UTC') AT TIME ZONE timezone.java_id) AS TIMESTAMP) )  BETWEEN '16-JUL-20' AND '16-JUL-20') 
          and c.site_id='917'

group by unit_id
)  ual2 on ual.unit_id=ual2.unit_id and ual.id= ual2.m_id 
join col$units u2 on u2.id=ual.unit_id
join col$collections c on c.id=u2.coll_id
INNER JOIN svc$sites site ON site.code = u2.site_id
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = site.timezone_id
group by ual.unit_id,u2.unit_num,u2.volume,c.id,cast(trunc((from_tz(cast(ual.log_ts as timestamp), 'UTC') at time zone timezone.java_id)) as timestamp),
c.site_id,u2.coll_id, u2.site_id,ual.old_value, ual.new_value) q1
join (
select  cast(trunc((from_tz(cast(ual.log_ts as timestamp), 'UTC') at time zone timezone.java_id)) as timestamp) as Month,
u2.unit_num as Count_waste,u2.volume as volume, u2.unit_num as unit_num,
ual.unit_id, max(ual.id) as max_id, c.id as c_id, u2.coll_id as u2_id, ual.new_value as new, c.site_id as site_id
from col$unit_action_log ual
join (select ual2.unit_id as unit_id, max(ual2.id) as M_id
from col$unit_action_log ual2 
join col$units u2 on u2.id=ual2.unit_id
join col$collections c on c.id=u2.coll_id
INNER JOIN svc$sites site ON site.code = u2.site_id
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = site.timezone_id
where  ( ual2.action_ind='RECLASS') and 
( trunc(CAST( (from_tz(CAST(ual2.log_ts AS TIMESTAMP),'UTC') AT TIME ZONE timezone.java_id) AS TIMESTAMP) )  BETWEEN '16-JUL-20' AND '16-JUL-20') 
and c.site_id='917'
---and trunc(ual2.log_ts)='13-JUL-20')        
--( ual2.action_ind='RECLASS' and trunc(ual2.log_ts)='13-JUL-20')
group by unit_id)  ual2 on ual.unit_id=ual2.unit_id and ual.id= ual2.m_id 
join col$units u2 on u2.id=ual.unit_id
join col$collections c on c.id=u2.coll_id
INNER JOIN svc$sites site ON site.code = u2.site_id
INNER JOIN svc$timezones timezone ON timezone.id = site.timezone_id
group by ual.unit_id,u2.unit_num,u2.volume,c.id,
--trunc(ual.log_ts),
cast(trunc((from_tz(cast(ual.log_ts as timestamp), 'UTC') at time zone timezone.java_id)) as timestamp),
c.site_id,u2.coll_id, u2.site_id,ual.old_value, ual.new_value) q2 on q2.site_id=q1.site_id and q1.unit_id=q2.unit_id
order by q1.unit_num, case when q2.new ='NSP' then 1 else 2 end;```
````